# How to keep WireGuard active and connected through suspends?

Tags: suspend, vpn, wireguard

On a Windows 10 machine I have an always-on WireGuard (0.5.3) VPN connection. Whenever it suspends, the connection is active right after the computer comes back up.

**How do I achieve the same effect on my Ubuntu 22.04?** Currently, when I suspend the system and it comes back up, the connection seems active (the interface is listed) but isn't (no response to icmp echo from hosts over VPN).

My config

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = prv+key=
Address = 192.168.2.23/32
DNS = 192.168.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = pub+key=
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.1/24, 192.168.2.1/24
Endpoint = gateway.domain.tld:51820
```

And I use wg-quick to bring it up

```
root@roaminglaptop:/etc/wireguard# wg-quick up only-lan.conf
```

Please note, that this is a different server from the one I use with a Windows machine. So it may be that the other peer is at fault here. Let me know if this should be investigated.